# Commerce Cloud + Marketing Cloud...OverKill or not?

Tags: marketing-cloud, trailhead, commerce-cloud

I have just made my way through the Commerce Cloud trailhead and noticed that it had a strong "merchandising and marketing module" capable of handling personalizations and to some extent customer journeys.

In light of this, is it feasible for a client to get both marketing cloud and commerce cloud? Are there gaps in their functionality or would it be duplicating ?

For reference the trailhead module can be found here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/cc-overview/modules/cc_cccapability/units/cc_cccapability_ccdigital

Comment: Mate, if your Account Executive says it's all about the "Customer Success Platform" and gets the brighter guy to demo the vision, you should just drink the blue coolade. It's one platform... ahem.

Comment: lol! Really irks me when they say that. They are fund of selling dreams and leaving us to pick up the slack

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is commerce cloud, EPIserver or other systems - there is a mandate for both, and I personally know of a couple of companies operating both Commerce and Marketing Cloud.

The main deciding point is to clarify which cloud will drive predictions of products - CC or MC, as this is where they overlap.

MC will drive any communication sent to customer. Landing pages can be in both systems, or one, depending on requirements, tracking etc.

CC will drive shopping / commerce experience.

Overall, I believe the key in this process is to ensure that you have the proper architecture in place, and the proper governance. Some of the questions that needs to be answered, among many, are:

- Do we have a tag manager in place? (to push collects scripts through) or is it a direct implementation?
- Which systems governs what experiences?

Marketing Cloud will, hands down, have the best tracking of the two systems - given that they can capture all the behavioural data from email, clicks, browse, sms clicks, apps etc. - meaning that over time, Marketing Cloud Einstein will probably be the rockstar of personal recommendations.

However, Commerce Cloud might be capable of better controlling page structure, user experience etc.

In essence, it all comes down to mapping, architecture and governance. What you would get, down the line, from running both would be a tighter integration and probably more direct synergies, which would be really interesting over time.

At present, I would advise to reach out to Salesforce directly, to hear what their vision for the split and relevance of the two products are.

Comment: Commerce Cloud is demandware was acquired by Salesforce last year and has almost comparable marketing ability to marketing cloud. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/cc-overview/modules/cc_cccapability/units/cc_cccapability_ccdigital

Comment: Yeah i know :) Haven't heard any architectural guidelines though. I would assume that, in time, there will be a direct plugin from CC to MC that allows for the integration of catalogs. But still, you would need governance - which product does what. Do  you use MC Einstein Predictive Web, or use CC's own? First and foremost it is a choice. But i believe MC's option is the only that goes across channels :)

Comment: The one guiding principle I have heard, when probing salesforce, is that we need to think about MC as the communications engine.

Comment: so based on your outline, and what's written in trailhead - the question becomes: Should you use CC's personalization engine, or MC's einstein? (regardless, the catalogs most likely need to be integrated). Would you agree?

Comment: Not entirely sure. The SF universe is full a plethora of duplicity and just needing to check if there is a strong enough proposition to use both.

Comment: There is - one is commerce, other is communication. Where you need to decide, is on how to achieve the best personalization - and here, I'd recommend to reach out to ask salesforce to get their views on pro/con and potentially product vision? :)

Comment: WTF is "Einstein", anyway? Yes, Predictive Intelligence has jumped on the bandwagon and it's "Einstein", too. This sounds like a Rep driven conversation and I'm guessing most readers have little interest in understanding their Rep's take on this is... Not constructive, but Jeez! I don't give a flying one for what AEs think... Spin and where's the "Oppty"...

If you have "Commerce Cloud" and use recommendations, leave it to "Commerce Cloud". It does it out of the box. It does it well by all accounts. Integrating with SFMC sounds all too possible, but why would you?

Comment: Well... you do get more behaviour data using PI than using commerce + it carries across experiences (from web to app), but as stated, i would liase with SF to advise on their suggestions and then combine with own architecture, operating model etc

Comment: @AndrewMcLeod You would integrate with MC because you really need to integrate with an ESP if you want to get the most out of that customer touch point. Commerce Cloud's email sending leaves much to be desired from both a programming perspective as well as a marketing perspective.